# What files in Service References must be deployed to consume a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I'm concerned about files should be included in a deployment of a .NET project.  I have console applications that are consuming a WCF service.  The WCF service is running over HTTP.  Do I need to deploy all the XSD, SVCINFO, WSDL & SVCMAP files that are in the Service References folder?

Thanks for any help.  I sure wish there was a single page at Microsoft that definitively explained what file types were required in a deployment.

Comment: There is such a page. It is blank, as you don't deploy anything in the Service Reference folder.

Answer (score 9):

The only bits you need at installation time are the compiled code and the .config file.  The rest of the pieces (the code, WSDL, etc) or all for compile / design time.

Comment: Thank-you both very much for your help!